# How to call a JS function before a jquery button click(click through selector)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, button

I want to call a JS function when a button is clicked and then continue execution of below `jquery` script

**Form :**

```
<form id="my_form">
  <button type="button" id="Bshift" onclick="validation()">Clear</button>
</form>
```

**Pure JS Function:**

```
function validation(){
    // this has to be executed  first
    // do something here..
}
```

**Jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#Bshift').submit(function(){
    // this has to be executed  second
    // do something here.
    }
});
```

I would like to know is how I execute my function before my jquery submit.

Comment: This is a very common error. You want to assign the *function* `validation` to yourr click handler. What you instead do is assign whatever the execution of that function ***returns*** by assigning the function execution `validation()` to the `onclick` handler.

Comment: I think you're confused. In jquery.

Comment: see this demo link http://jsfiddle.net/oaefktpb/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
  <form id="my_form">
    <button type="button" id="Bshift">Clear</button>
  </form>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#Bshift').on('click', function(){ // I think this should be click event because you're not submitting your page you're just clearing it based on "CLEAR"
     validation();
   }

   function validation(){
    do something here..
   }
 }
```

**Note:** Your function must be outside the event triggers.

Answer (score 0):

Call your validation function inside submit call.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('#Bshift').submit(function(){
        validation()
        do something here.
        }
    }
```

HTML Code

```
<button type="button" id="Bshift" >Clear</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have one more option to submit the form through ajax after validation.

```
$('my_form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (validation()){
        $.ajax({...});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited code, please test my code.

```
<script>
function validation(){
    alert('How are you?');
}

$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#Bshift').click(function(){
         validation(); 
         alert('Fine and you?');           
     });
 });
</script>

<form id="my_form">
<button type="button" id="Bshift">Clear</button>
</form>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/oaefktpb/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Invoke validation function on form submit event

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    validation(); // function call

    $('#my_form').submit(function(){  //form submit event
    // do something here.
    }

});


function validation(){
 // do something here..
}
```